# Can't found Run menu in context menu

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelIJ, Java project

I create Main.java class

But I get error. Not found `java.util.logging.*`

And when I mouse right click, not found "Run.

[image]

I set SDK to java 8 but it not help
[image]

Comment: What you show is a Platform Settings. Check Project SDK (under `Project Settings > Project`).

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yes, thanks. After I set SDK 8, then show Run context  menu.

Comment: *then show Run context menu* - I'm not sure what you mean.. have you solved your problem?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yes,      Project structure-> Project settings->Project, set Project SDK = 1.8

Comment: At the first screenshot, let's take screenshot of full screen.